# Pass Array Between Child Components Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am trying to pass an array from one child component to another. I have tried following some of the tutorials online to share data with a service, but this doesn't seem to be working for me and causes my page not to load anything.

What was breaking my program was adding the DataService to the constructor:

```
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

export class BodyComponent implements OnInit{
  films = [{Title: "Finding Nemo", Rating: "3.5"}, {Title: "Rambo", Rating: "4.0"}];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private data: DataService) { }
}
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private finalNoms = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentNoms = this.finalNoms.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeNominations(nom: Object){
    this.finalNoms.next(nom);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you indicate how the app was broken when dataService was added (what error message and/or behavior) ?
How are you using this dataService in the BodyComponent ?

Comment: so basically nothing would load on the screen, and if I inspect the page, the <app-header> and <app-body> sections appear, but there is nothing inside of them. I am also missing my <app-footer>

Comment: the use of the dataService will be to add movies to a list, or remove from the list.

Answer (score 1):

In angular it's the service who manages the data. You should put `films = [{Title: "Finding Nemo", Rating: "3.5"}, {Title: "Rambo", Rating: "4.0"}];` in your service and access to it in your component by doing in the constructor or ngOnInit:

```
this.films = this.data.films;
```

Other thing: you should name (in your component) your service dataService instead of justdata.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to add where your service is provided:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

That should fix your errors.

Comment: this solved the issue with things not loading, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to pass an array of data between 2 child components, it's probably best to create 2 ViewChilds in your parent and pass the data up to the parent via EventEmitter and back down to the other child.